# Publish major version for all documents in library

Tags: document-library, versioning

Is there a way you can publish major version for all the documents in a document library in one go?

I have tried switching the Versioning Settings from "Create major and minor (draft) versions" to "Create major versions" and back but that didn't automatically publish a version for the documents.

**Edit:**

Ok, I found out that you could do it using SharePoint Designer by opening the library -> select all files -> check out -> check in as major version.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually, you don't need SharePoint Designer in order to achieve this. Instead you can use "**Content and Structure**" which is built into the SharePoint UI itself.

"Content and Structure" is availabe on the Site Settings page after you have turned on the Site Collection scoped feature "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" (this is the name in SharePoint 2010).

Comment: thanks you for this post.. really helped. saved me hours!

Comment: I never knew this! I always powershelled it! Cheers!

Comment: Perfect! I'll add, that in SharePoint Online this feature is hidden (from site-collection admins too), but You can access using direct url: https://server/_layouts/15/sitemanager.aspx